# Can Script using object work as what "make single user" does?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

A while ago I’ve read about what “Make Single User” does and tested it. Which was totally amazing and mind blowing.

e.g. later I learned about few Python scripts with which it is possible to move UV faces and even their vertex points in order to shift textures on planes.

And wanted to find out is there any way of how to get a python script using object to work as what “Make Single User” does?

As every new Python script using object which gets spawned into scene would work simultaneously with previously spawned in object, even if I move empty in between spawning in the object while its processes would affect every single new spawned in object which is using the same instance of the .py script.

Been trying to type with many variations of keywords in order to try to find at least someone else on the web who was looking for solution but unfortunately so far I had no luck.

Any hints please?

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello ! I think your question is a bit convoluted, could you add a simple diagram or interface screenshots showing off exactly what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I've just added x3 screenshots containing what I was on about. There's the script, which is not in the state in which i'd want to use it for some purposes. The mouse over logic setup, as well as the empty stuff to spawn it into scene. It was just testing in this case to move the individual UV vertex points.

Comment: Basically if I would action a shapekeyed "cube". Which 
gets spawned into scene while passed through an empty hooked 
up with keyboard sensor e.g key A, and connected
through "And" controller, which gets connected to 
"Edit object" and select "cube" in add object - object
drop down selector inside of Blenders logic 
editor. The "cube" could be 
hooked up with key "S" for its keyboard sensor 
and connected to "and" controller, followed 
by connecting it to Action actuator which would play 
the shape key of the "cube" e.g. WITHOUT  make single user -

Comment: - enabled, and if 10 cubes would get spawned into scene, then by 
pressing S to play the key action, all of the 10 
 cubes would execute their actions in the same time. 
But if I'd add mouseover sensor connected to what S key is connected to to execute action, 
Then - no matter over which of 10 spawned in cubes 
I would mouse over and press S to play the key action, 
they would play the actioned shapekey only on those which get 
mouse over while "s" is being pressed.

Comment: e.g. an object set with "always sensor" set on true,
would get passed to a script, which is moving UV faces over
the texture to make it to look like texture is sliding over
the plane. If I'd add multiple planes in the scene, they all
would be functioning by the same script to which the plane is 
connected to, no matter even if I motion the empty so that 
the next plane with UV unwrap moved by the script would
do the same what previously spawned in plane would do to 
prevent them of being spawned or added one on each other.

Comment: As the "make single user" does not apply to script using object
or object using the script.
Therefor I am writing this thing here so that I could potentially
find all of the best ways to optimize some features in my 
project to its maximum. Though
there are other alternatives of how to get around of this
while I would like to know if what I am looking for is possible at
all. Which is to make e.g. script using object to work
as what "make single user" feature does.

Comment: Oh okay you should have prefaced your question by saying you're using 2.79 and the game engine, also you should put all that in your question. But sorry, not my area of expertise so I can't really help you

Comment: I don't know, while I personally think that I've totally 
nailed it by writing what I wrote. 
And I think that if someone with some decent experience
of Blender or scripting would read this - would understand it clearly. 
But cheers for 
hitting me up, I had a buzzing moment of someones attention 
wrapped in excitement which almost made me to cough up my heart 
from the hopeful feeling that maybe I'm lucky
today to find out. As i'm with severe and manic 
urges of getting to know how to achieve that.
=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been lucky that someone bothered to read my questions and eventually I have got my spider fingers on what I was looking for.

Works perfectly once added to a mouse object with mouse over any sensor looking for objects property to end them upon pressing the LMB button.

import bge

Cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
Own = Cont.owner
ClickSens = Cont.sensors["MClick"]
OverSens = Cont.sensors["MOver"]

if ClickSens.positive:
Target = OverSens.hitObject
if Target:
Target.endObject()